# Does the following differential equation have a unique solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In a sufficiently small neighborhood around $x=2$ the differential equation

$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{y}{\sqrt{x}}, y(2)=4\;$ has a unique solution. How do I prove this?

My attempt has so far been to find the solution of the differential equation as
$$\log(y^2) = 2\sqrt{x} + 2\log(4) - 2\sqrt{2}$$

Is this solution unique? In the neighborhood of $2$ and what happens if we choose some other value of $x$?

Answer (score 1):

Existence. The function $y(x)=4\exp(2\sqrt{x}-2\sqrt{2})$, $x\in (0,\infty)$ satisfies
the IVP
$$
y'=\frac{y}{\sqrt{x}}, \quad y(2)=4.
$$
Uniqueness. If $\varphi: I\to\mathbb R$ is another solution, then
$$
\varphi'(x)-\frac{\varphi(x)}{\sqrt{x}}=0
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
\exp(-2\sqrt{x})\big(\varphi'(x)-\frac{\varphi(x)}{\sqrt{x}}\big)=0 \\
\big(\exp(-2\sqrt{x})\varphi(x)\big)'=0
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad \exp(-2\sqrt{x})\varphi(x)=c
$$
for some constant $c\in\mathbb R$, and hence
$$
\varphi(x)=c\exp(2\sqrt{x}).
$$
Incorporating the initial data, we obtain that $c=4\exp(-2\sqrt{2}),$ and hence $\varphi\equiv y$.